# Spark sql server query generates sub-query on non indexed column

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, jdbc, query-optimization

I have a spark job that reads from a sql server using jdbc connector

The table is indexed on columns named `insertion_time` and `car_id`.

At first the query I tried to use to read the table with was:

```
SELECT car_id, km_traveled, fuel_used, manufacturing_date, insertion_time
FROM car_info
WHERE insertion_time > '2022-01-01 00:00:01' AND km_traveled > 1000'
```

This query received a timeout as the table is not indexed on the `km_traveled` column.

So I changed the query I use to read from the table to:

```
SELECT car_id, km_traveled, fuel_used, manufacturing_date, insertion_time
FROM car_info
WHERE insertion_time > '2022-01-01 00:00:01'
```

Then, immediately after the data is read I perform a filter `km_traveled > 1000` (in the spark execution job as opposed to the read query).

Spark sees this filter and generates an optimized sub-query adding `WHERE km_traveled > 1000` to the read query sent to the DB.

However, since the table is not indexed on the `km_traveled` column, and the table has 1,500,000,000 rows, I believe this optimization is actually slowing down my query to a point where it still receives a timeout the aborts the query.

My question is, is there a way to disable such an optimization?

I saw that optimization rules in general can be disabled in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268704/disable-spark-catalyst-optimizer). But I could not find the specific rule that disables the aforementioned optimization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What columns does your index (presumably) on `insertion_time` `INCLUDE`? I suspect the real problem is your index isn't covering. Moving the column `km_traveled` from the `WHERE` to the `SELECT` is only likely to make the query slower if the column isn't in the `INCLUDE`, as the data engine now needs to scan *and* return that column or look it up as part of the key lookup.

Comment: A "non optimized query" - your term - would have to retrieve all 1,500,000,000 rows and then search in them (in the client?) for the km_traveled > 1000 records ... so that sounds bad too. As noted above, better to provide a covering index, so that the filtering can happen on the server without having to scan all rows in the table.

Comment: Timeouts could also be that it generates statistics for km_traveled column, before creating appropriate query plan. You can usually see it in Activity Monitor if you see a query which doesn't nothing and cannot be shown in Query Plan mode

Comment: I'm not really buying that the addition of `AND km_traveled > 1000` is the problem here. You say there is no index on that column so I would expect the plan to be much the same as whatever the plan for `SELECT car_id, km_traveled, fuel_used, manufacturing_date, insertion_time
FROM car_info
WHERE insertion_time > '2022-01-01 00:00:01'` is but with a residual predicate. Your question is missing information about whether `SELECT car_id, km_traveled, fuel_used, manufacturing_date, insertion_time
FROM car_info
WHERE insertion_time > '2022-01-01 00:00:01'` also timesout

Comment: Though the `km_traveled > 1000` predicate could cause auto stats update as suggested by  siggemannen

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this in Spark, but the workaround for this is usually to use a row-goal `TOP` on the query before adding the extra filter

```sql
SELECT car_id, km_traveled, fuel_used, manufacturing_date, insertion_time
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1000000000) *
    FROM car_info
    WHERE insertion_time > '2022-01-01 00:00:01'
) t
WHERE km_traveled > 1000'
```

Incidentally, the optimum index for this query is probably one which has `INCLUDE` columns

```
INDEX IX NONCLUSTERED (insertion_time)
  INCLUDE (car_id, km_traveled, fuel_used, manufacturing_date)
```

Bear in mind that the server might actually be right that `km_traveled` is a better column to filter on. In which case you would use

```
INDEX IX NONCLUSTERED (km_traveled)
  INCLUDE (car_id, insertion_time, fuel_used, manufacturing_date)
```

Note that you cannot add both columns to the index to get an efficient result, as the `WHERE` clauses are both inequalities (they do not use `=`).